# Why segmentation fault after altering pointer to struct?

Tags: c, file, pointers, segmentation-fault

I currently have functioning code, that when I attempted to make a function out of the conversion of a file to array, I get a segmentation fault.  I know that the objects inside of `fileToArray` are correct (as far as the `myData` objects are concerned) because when inside of the function, the `myData.length`, and `myData.array` all return correctly.  However, after the pointer is referenced in the main, I get a seg fault.  I'm new to c, but all of this is working without that specific pointer to the struct.

So, if I call this program with an argument with a file with multiple rows of text, the set fault happens.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct {
    int length;
    char** array;
} FileStruct;

void fileToArray(FileStruct* fileDataPtr, int argc, char *argv[]){
    int  fd, i, n, count;
    struct stat statbuf;
    char *buf, *inbuf, *str, *saveptr;
    char **array;

    if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1) {
        printf("Error opening file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit (-1);
    }

    if (lstat(argv[1], &statbuf) < 0) {
        printf("Unable to lstat file %s\n", argv[1]);
        exit (-1);
    }
    off_t filesize = statbuf.st_size;
    buf = malloc(sizeof(char)*filesize);
    array = malloc(sizeof(char *)*filesize);

    count = 0;
    if ((n = read(fd, buf, filesize)) > 0){
        inbuf = buf;
        for (i = 1; ; inbuf = NULL, i++) {
            str = strtok_r(inbuf, "\n", &saveptr); 
            if (str == NULL)
               break;
            array[count] = malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(str)+1));
            strcpy(array[count++], str);
        }
    } else {
        printf("Error reading input file\n");
        exit (-1);
    }

    close(fd);

    // I know array works because it prints correctly here.
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    free(array[i]);
    }

    fileDataPtr->length = count;
    fileDataPtr->array = array;

    free(array);
    free(buf);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;

    FileStruct myData;
    FileStruct* fileDataPtr = &myData;
    fileToArray(fileDataPtr, argc, argv);

    printf("length: %i", myData.length);

    // I know this doesn't work because anything related to myData causes Seg fault.
    // for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    //     printf("%s\n", myData.array[i]);
    //     free(myData.array[i]);
    // }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either use a debugger or divide an conquer - add some printfs to narrow down the actual line causing the crash.

Comment: Hey, thanks.  I already added printf's which is why I know that everything works up until the point where I use anything related to `myData`.  Whether it's printing `myData.length` or anything from `myData.array` I get the same error.  So I know the error is right there.  Just not sure how to resolve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the end of `fileToArray`, you assign `array` to `fileDataPtr->array`, then on the next line you free `array`.  This will leave `fileDataPtr->array` pointing to freed memory (a dangling pointer).  When you dereference it later, you're into Undefined Behavior and anything can happen.

Since the assignment transfers ownership of the allocated memory to `fileDataPtr`, you do not need to free `array` before returning from `fileToArray`.

Remove the `free(array);` line.

Comment: Thanks, I'd been looking at this for a long time!  I hate that it was something so simple, but I guess that's the thing I'm most likely to overlook being this new to C.